# embed font-face doesn't working when use "sans-serif" default font (bootstrap 4)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, font-face, font-family

I'm using in my website embed font-face.it's working without **sans-serif** font but i write this **font-family: 'roboto-bold',sans-serif;** its not working.i'm also use bootstrap 4. and i m not using bootstrap 4 then its work.

```css
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'roboto-regular',sans-serif;
    src: url('./fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('./fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-display: swap;
  }


  body{
    font-family: 'roboto-regular',sans-serif;
  }
  
  .tab-title{
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'roboto-regular',sans-serif;
  color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <title>Demo</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="demostyle.css">

</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h3 class="tab-title"> Overview</h3>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can only see that you are using `roboto-regular` on both `<body>` and `.tab-title`. If you want to use the `roboto-bold` then that should be used as the `font-family`.